# How do you send a full response to a web browser using C in a simple http server?

Tags: c, http

Please help, I am attempting to write a basic http server in C. I have had success in producing a result but the result is not what I was going for. The browser is only rendering one character and I can't figure out why. Below is my server code as of right now. Anything you can do to help would be most appreciated. You're the best!

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PORT 8080

int clients[1000];

int handle(int socket, int fd, struct sockaddr *pSockaddr, socklen_t *pInt, char *output);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                   &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
            sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* httpVersion = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
    char* contentLength = "Content-Length: 1\r\n";
    char* server = "Server: n\r\n";
    char output[30000];
    char* contentType = "Content-Type: text/html";
    char* newLine = "\r\n";
    strncat(output, httpVersion, strlen(httpVersion));
    strncat(output, contentLength, strlen(contentLength));
    strncat(output, server, strlen(server));
    strncat(output, contentType, strlen(contentType));
    strncat(output, newLine, strlen(newLine));
    strncat(output, newLine, strlen(newLine));
    strncat(output, "abc", strlen("abc"));
    strncat(output, newLine, strlen(newLine));
    strncat(output, newLine, strlen(newLine));

    while(1){

        if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
        {
            perror("listen");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        struct sockaddr *sa = (struct sockaddr *)&address;
        socklen_t *sl = (socklen_t*)&addrlen;
        handle(new_socket, server_fd, sa, sl, output);
    }
}


int handle(int new_socket, int server_fd, struct sockaddr *sa, socklen_t *sl, char *output) {

    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, sa, sl))<0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    write(new_socket, output, strlen(output));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `output` is uninitialized.  Try doing `output[0] = '\0';` prior to all your `strncat` calls.

Comment: You only need to listen() once.  It is accept() that needs to be looped to handle multiple connections.  Also, you MUST correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like write().  'int clientfd = clients[new_socket];' clients is uninitialized, so UB.

Comment: @MartinJames I defined clients as a variable above, what do you mean?

Comment: @MartinJames thank you for the listen tidbit, I thought there was something wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example on port 3000.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 3000

int clients[1000];
wchar_t output[3000];

int handle(int socket, int fd, struct sockaddr *pSockaddr, socklen_t *pInt, char *output);

void tostring(char *size, int length);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                   &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
            sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* content = "abc";
    char* httpVersion = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
    char* contentLengthTitle = "Content-Length: ";
    int length = strlen(content);

    char *contentLengthSize[3000];
    tostring(contentLengthSize, length);
    char* newLine = "\r\n";
    char contentLength[3000];
    strncat(contentLength, contentLengthTitle, strlen(contentLengthTitle));
    strncat(contentLength, contentLengthSize, strlen(contentLengthSize));
    strncat(contentLength, newLine, strlen(newLine));

    char* server = "Server: n\r\n";
    char* contentType = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    strncat(output, httpVersion, strlen(httpVersion));
    strncat(output, contentLength, strlen(contentLength));
    strncat(output, server, strlen(server));
    strncat(output, contentType, strlen(contentType));
    strncat(output, newLine, strlen(newLine));
    strncat(output, newLine, strlen(newLine));
    strncat(output, content, strlen(content));
    strncat(output, newLine, strlen(newLine));
    strncat(output, newLine, strlen(newLine));

    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(1){
        struct sockaddr *sa = (struct sockaddr *)&address;
        socklen_t *sl = (socklen_t*)&addrlen;
        handle(new_socket, server_fd, sa, sl, output);
    }
}



int handle(int new_socket, int server_fd, struct sockaddr *sa, socklen_t *sl, char *output) {

    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, sa, sl))<0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

//    char buffer[1024] = {0};
//    read(new_socket , buffer, 1024);
    write(new_socket, output, strlen(output));
    return 0;
}
void tostring(char *str, int num) {

    int i, rem, len = 0, n;

    n = num;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        len++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        rem = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        str[len - (i + 1)] = rem + '0';
    }
    str[len] = '\0';
}


void tostring(char str[], int num);
```

Comment: So you wrote a fucntional minimal server just to answer this question and then did not spend any effort on explanations? Or did you copy this from somewhere?

Comment: Is there a special reason that you provide the prototype of `void tostring(char str[], int num);` again and AFTER defining that function, but not exactly identically?

Comment: @Yunnosch No, I fumbled along. I started with https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/. If you don't feel this is valuable I will take it down. There are no articles online on how to serve up a browser response.